# how to derive a function defined with a summatory

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Probably I'm missing something very easy but I don't know what to do in this case: let $f(x)$ be a function defined with a summatory, for a trivial example:

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^x k$$

Now this kind functions is defined only for nonnegative integers so let suppose that it could be anallitically continued on the whole $\Bbb R$ (or at least at every nonnegative real numbers).
What is the derivative of this function ? In general how do I derive a function where the argument is the number of terms of a summatory (or even a productory would be interesting to me) ?

Comment: Your function is well defined when $x$ is a non-negative integer.  but what for example does  $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{1.5} k\, $ mean? I could imagine you wanting it to be $1$ or $1.875$ depending on how you extend the function.

Comment: @Henry I was waiting for a comment like that, I try to edit my question.

Comment: Your question amounts to solving the following recursive functional equation:
$f(x+1)=f(x)+x+1$ with $f(0)=0$... but I haven't really thought on how to solve it yet :)

Comment: Well.. $f(x):=\frac{x^2+x}{2}$ just does the trick :)

Comment: It depends on how you are continuing it.  In the case you give, you could have $f(x) = f(\lfloor x \rfloor)$, which then has derivative zero away from non-negative integers, and is not differentiable at integers.  If, instead, you continue with a linear interpolation, so say $f(x) = (f(k+1)-f(k))(x-k) + f(k)$ on $[k,k+1)$ then the derivative will be $k+1$ on $[k,k+1)$, and will again not be differentiable at the integers.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a complete answer, but after one of the comments above, I thought I'd mention it.  Your particular example is equivalent to the functional equation $f(x+1)=f(x)+x+1$.  Differentiate both sides, and you get $f'(x+1)=f'(x)+1$, which can be easily solved to obtain $$f'(x)=f'(0)+x.$$  Integrate, and we get $$f(x)-f(0)=\frac{1}{x}x^2+xf'(0).$$  If we want $f$ to agree with your original summation if $x$ is an integer, plug in $x=1$ and we get $$1=f(1)=\frac{1}{2}+f'(0),$$ so that $f'(0)=\frac{1}{2}$.  In conclusion, we obtain $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}x=\frac{(x+1)x}{2}.$$ This is particularly nice, since it's the same formula you would get from the finite arithmetic series formula.  Also, the derivative is $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}+x$, as obtained near the beginning.

There's a way to extend this idea to things like $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^x g_k(x),$$ so that at the very least, the derivatives at integer arguments "make sense".  However, today is Mother's day, so I'm going to go have supper with my mother.  I'll update my answer later this evening or tomorrow once I have it written out.  However, this post itself should give you an idea of one possible avenue to explore.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post it as an answer since it is one.
A solution to the functional equation (which is indeed equivalent to your stated problem):

> $$f(x+1)-f(x)=x+1$$ $$f(0)=0$$

is $f(x):=\frac{x^2+x}{2}$

Indeed:
$$f(x+1)-f(x)= \frac{(x+1)^2+(x+1)}{2}-\frac{x^2+x}2=\frac{2x+2}{2}=x+1$$
as requested.

(Clearly I'm only claiming that this is *a* solution, not *the* solution)

Comment: Okay I'm starting to get this but the function I wrote was just a trivial example, now if I understood right when I have a function defined with a summatory to derive it I have to interpolate it linearly and then derivate it, air ?

Comment: I am not sure you can jump to such conlcusion that fast... but because of my uncertainty I'd rather not give you a full answer. Maybe some other user can help you further....